# Determining tense of werden when converting a sentence into passive

Tags: passive

> Convert the sentence into passive:
>
> Unsere ersten Produkte gerieten zu schnell in Vergessenheit
>
> My answer: Unsere ersten Produkte werden zu schnell vergessen.
>
> Actual answer: Unsere ersten Produkte wurden zu schnell vergessen.

Why did we use werden in the past tense instead of present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did we use *werden* in the past tense instead of present?

Because also the original sentence uses the verb in the past tense (*gerieten*) and not present (*geraten*).

- Produkte *geraten* in Vergessenheit → Produkte *werden vergessen* (Präsens)
- Produkte *gerieten* in Vergessenheit → Produkte *wurden vergessen* (Präteritum)
- Produkte *sind* in Vergessenheit *geraten* → Produkte *sind vergessen worden* (Perfekt)

---

**Addition:** Even though I haven't written anything about *passive*, some people demand that I mention that, technically, the conversion is not from active form to passive form of the same verb (*gefallen*), but from active form of one verb (*gefallen*) to passive form of another (*vergessen*). Nevertheless, this does not affect the essence of the question regarding the tenses.

Comment: Oh oops, make sense

Comment: -1 Because the verb can't be put into passiv. You've just put "vergessen" into Passiv, nothing more.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana, I did not write anything about passive! I just explained why the tenses are as they are and, actually, that was the essence of the question. Therefore, your downvoting is unjustified.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich No, it is not. You misled by equating "in Vergessenheit geraten" with "vergessen". This is incorrect.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana, wenn Sie die Frage richtig lesen würden, würden Sie feststellen, dass der Satz nicht von mir stammt, sondern schon vorgegeben war. Ich erkläre hier lediglich, wieso er im Präteritum steht. Das Wort *passive* kam bei mir überhaupt nicht vor (außer jetzt im Zusatz).

Answer (score 1):

> Convert the sentence into passive:
>
> Unsere ersten Produkte gerieten zu schnell in Vergessenheit.
>
> Actual answer: Unsere ersten Produkte wurden zu schnell vergessen.

The answer key is wrong. Passive voice means that the subject must be converted into an adverbial or dropped from the sentence. But your answer key retains the subject.

Actually, you can't convert this sentence into passive voice at all because the verb *geraten* assigns no agency. It's a so called *unaccusative verb* that treats its subject like an accusative object.

A similar verb you may know better is *gefallen*.

> Du gefällst mir.

*Du* does nothing. It has no agency. *I* do something though I am the dative object. *Du* is passive though this is an active voice sentence. That's why it makes no sense to build a passive voice for *gefallen*. And it's the same for

> Du gerätst in Vergessenheit.

Again *du* does nothing. Everyone in the world **but you** forgets you. *Du* is the only one who does nothing in the sentence.

---

What your answer key does instead is using another verb *vergessen* which has agency and also an accusative object. But the active voice sentence for

> Unsere ersten Produkte wurden zu schnell vergessen.

is of course

> Sie vergaßen unsere ersten Produkte zu schnell.

which is very different from your example sentence. See how the subject *Sie* is dropped from the active sentence to get to your answer key, and how the accusative object *unsere ersten Produkte* becomes the subject in your answer key?

Comment: The second sentence isn't the passive of the first sentence, but a passive sentence synonymous with it. I don't see a problem.

Comment: The assignment should say that then.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It cannot answer the question because the premises of the question are wrong and I explained why. If the premise was "find something synonymous" instead, the tense is arbitrary.

Comment: @SBrian Please mark this answer as the correct one. The current is misleading and incorrect.